# How to continuously read an online/web file in java?

Tags: java, http, web, text, continuous

I am making a simple text-only instant messenger in java. The way that it currently works is that all the messages are put into an online text file by sending a php file a request (I know this is bad for security, but this is just to learn how to do web-connected apps in java.)
Currently, I am continually fetching the entire contents of the messages.txt file and placing them into my JTextPane like this:

```java
while(true) {
URL url = new URL("{path to text file}");
InputStream in = url.openStream();
Scanner s = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A");
String conversation = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
textPane.setText(conversation);
}
```

But when the conversation becomes long enough, it lags as it is fetching 100kb+ files constantly from a web server.

What I want to happen is to only read the changes to the file so that it doesn't lag and max out my internet connection by requesting enourmous amounts of plain text files. I don't want to just make it run every 2 seconds because it's an *instant* messenger, no delays.

How would I go around only fetching the changes to the file and adding them to the text pane?

Answer (score 0):

Can you push the file contents to another file once it crosses a certain threshold. This will ensure that you operate upon a smaller file.

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of contacting url directly you could place some server side script that would call the file

You could (as a client) provide the server script the last line / message identifier and the server could respond with new messages that have been added **after** the message id that the client has provided. In addition it could send the new last message id

With this approach the server side script doesnt even need to read itself the whole file and instead can immediately skip to the required line if message id contains the information about the line in the log file

Of course this approach is really far from real scenarios but its ok for learning IMO

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: You'll need some technology that runs server side code. The choice is broad. In java world you can start with tomcat or if you already mentioned php in the question keep working with it...